# Intrepretation of Unit ID from NMEA data

Tags: gps, gis, nmea

I have tested a tracking device (AVL) after developing a TCP Server but instead of giving out a unit ID as per what I configured it, it gives in a totally different format as follows:

$$ h?sp _ ÖU163240.298,A,0118.3741,S,03645.3077,E,001. 5,010.2,011011,,,

where $$ h?sp _ ÖU should be indicating the unit ID. And I believe that $$ and ÖU are separators. The unit ID I configured was 10737020005. How can i interpret such data so that I get the clear Unit ID. I thought it was Hex but it seems not since Hex uses 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F.

I have tested configuring several different devices of the same type but all send UNIT ID in that format e.g. $$ f?sp _ ÖU and $$ V?tIô2  ÖU

Could any one assist in interpreting.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a guess work given that your question doesn't seem to provide all necessary details:

- Only people who had prior experience in the tracking device you use may really help you.
- Be explicit describing the device,  hopefully refer to a (developer) manual.

I'm afraid it has to do with some "encoding" or "obfuscating" but I can't tell. A hashcode? nobody knows.

Why not Edit or post another new question. In case it was solved please share.

Comment: I haven't got the solution. In case I get, I'll share it over.